# How to implement pagination for relation field in Strapi?

Tags: node.js, strapi

I'm using Strapi as my backend framework for a web application, and I have encountered an issue regarding pagination for relations. Specifically, I'm trying to implement pagination for a relation field in one of my models.

Let's say I have two models: "Category" and "Article." Each Category can have multiple Articles, and I want to paginate the Articles related to a particular user. However, I haven't been able to find a straightforward way to achieve this in Strapi.

This is client code:

```
 const query = {
    populate: {
      articles: true //pagination (for example get the first 10 items or second 10 items)
    }
  };
  const queryToString = qs.stringify(query, { encode: false });
  const {
    data: { data: categories },
  } = await axiosApiInstance.get(
    `${BACKEND_BASE_URL}categories/${id}?${queryToString}`
  );
```

Based on the [documentation](https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/api/rest/populate-select#combining-population-with-other-operators), **The population and pagination operators cannot be combined**.

Can someone guide me on how to implement pagination specifically for relation fields in Strapi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in the Strapi source code itself. it's not in the documentation.

We can use **limit** and **start** directly in the **populate** field.

```
const query = {
  populate: {
    articles: {
      sort: "title:asc",
      limit: 10,
      start: 10,
    },
  },
};
const queryToString = qs.stringify(query, { encode: false });
const {
  data: { data: categories },
} = await axiosApiInstance.get(
  `${BACKEND_BASE_URL}categories/${id}?${queryToString}`
);
```